# Word for something being calm and weird at the same time

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes a scenario that feels both calm and odd at the same time. Like it's weird that it's so calm right now, but it is. Sort of like calm before the storm, ***but there may or may not be a storm.*** I thought it was eerie but eerie includes fear or frightening.

Comment: 'Charged' implies a change not yet happening. But it does not entail calmness. There's also 'pregnant', as in 'a pregnant pause'.

Comment: _ominous_, maybe.

Comment: "Uncanny" has some of the same "fear-inducing" connotations as "eerie", but might be a good fit.

Comment: @user888379 I think this is the closest one :) "strange or mysterious, especially in an unsettling way."

Comment: If you want a word that suggests the least odd, I'd go with an adjective before *still* as in "unusually still*. Even *uncanny* is stronger than this.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a word for what you are looking for exactly. Take a look at onelook. It is a reverse dictionary. http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml?s=calm%20weird Then check word by word until you get what is closer to what you want to express.

Comment: "Eerie" or "uncanny" would be what I would use.

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't a single word that incorporates the stillness, IMO this adjective can have the connotation of occurring in calmness, probably because of the nouns it often modifies and a setting used to portend an event.

**preternatural**

> Preternatural abilities, qualities, or events are very unusual in a
> way that might make you think that unknown forces are involved.
>
> **preternaturally** ADVERB
> *It was suddenly preternaturally quiet.* [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/preternatural)

> Beyond what is normal or natural. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/preternatural)

---

> Something made the skin on the back of Arnau's neck prickle – a
> **preternatural** feeling, and as they moved to the horses, his gaze
> strayed up. [S .J. A. Turney; *City of God*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/City_of_God/BASWDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22preternatural%20feeling%22&pg=PT264&printsec=frontcover)

> I sat in the clearing on the hilltop, and waited in the
> **preternatural** stillness so unlike the noisiness of the harshly sunny summer days that had greeted me. [K. J. Atchity and R McKenna;
> *The Classical Greek Reader*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Classical_Greek_Reader/rHJjAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22preternatural%20stillness%22&pg=PR18&printsec=frontcover)

> A central image in both poems is the **preternatural** "calm before
> the storm" a natural image that both poets use to characterize a
> scene in which a man is about to inflict a mortal blow upon an utterly
> helpless and passive victim, and then delivers it. [J. M. Ortiz;
> *Shakespeare and the Culture of Romanticism*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Shakespeare_and_the_Culture_of_Romantici/TR6oDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=preternatural%20calm%20before%20the%20storm&pg=PT193&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

Try *supernatural* which suggests an oddity without fright.